# Comments are getting executed in java

Tags: java

I happen to observe the below code where the comments are getting executed.. Not sure why this happens.Can anyone explain the logic behind it? What is \u000d

```
class Main{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // The comment below is getting executed
        // \u000d System.out.println("This comment is getting printed!"); 
    } 
} 



Output:
This comment is getting printed!
```

Comment: Did you tried to comment it like this

/* This is the beginning of a
multi-line comment
this is the end */

Comment: Yes , but still the line gets executed